# Why does my program freezes at string::insert()?

Tags: c++, string, insert

```
void Obenglobish::work()
{
    for (int i = 0; i<word.length(); i++)
    {
        if (word[i] == 'a')
        {
            word.insert(i, "ob");
        }

    }
}
```

My program runs fine till it reaches this statement, I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: It finds a, inserts 'ob' before it, find that a again, inserts... you got an infinite loop.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That is an awnser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to replace all instances of "a" with "ob" then consider using [string::replace](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/).

If you want to insert "ob" before all instances of "a" you will need to modify the loop variable by incrementing it by the length of the inserted text (in this case 2).

```
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) 
{
    if (word[i] == 'a')
    {
        word.insert(i, "ob");
        i += 2;
    }
}
```